# Order By Aggregate Functions SQL

Tags: sql

I want to get the count of `booking_class_rcd` as `NoOfPax`, Sum of `FareAmount` as `Total Fare`, Sum of `commission_amount` as `TotalCommission` on a particular flight date. I can’t get the right query.

`Booking_Class_rcd` – `'N'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'D'`

```
 Select agency_code,departure_date, booking_class_rcd, COUNT(booking_class_rcd)
       AS NoOfPax,origin_rcd, destination_rcd,SUM (fare_amount) as TotalFare,Sum(commission_amount) as TotalCommissionAmount
        from passenger_segment_mapping
    WHERE agency_code=’TEST’
    Group By booking_class_rcd
    Order by departure_date desc
```

My Result looks like.

```
    AgencyCode TEST Departure Date Booking_Class_rcd NoOfPax, origin, destination, TotalFareAmount TotalCommissionAmount
    TEST 2018-06-03 B 10 KTM PKR 30000 3000
    TEST 201806-03 C  20 KTM PKR 20000  2000
```

Comment: What *should* the result look like? What's wrong with what you have? Can you supply sample data? We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is. :)

Comment: Also, are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? That query isn't valid T-SQL, neither `agency_code ` or `departure_date` are in the `GROUP BY` or contained in an aggregate function. Also, SQL Server doesn't use backticks for quote operators. Thus the result you are saying you are getting is impossible for SQL Server with that SQL. When you update your post as per my comments above please also update your tags accordingly. I've removed the SQL Server and T-SQL tags, as they are clearly wrong.

Comment: You probably need to add `departure date` to `group by`: ``group by agency_code,departure_date, booking_class_rcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you are using MySQL which allows non-standard `group by` queries. The SQL standard requires that all "non-aggregating" columns are used to define the groups in the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT
        /* non-aggregating columns */
    agency_code
  , departure_date
  , booking_class_rcd
  , origin_rcd
  , destination_rcd

       /* aggregating columns */
  , COUNT(booking_class_rcd) AS noofpax
  , SUM(fare_amount)         AS totalfare
  , SUM(commission_amount)   AS totalcommissionamount

FROM passenger_segment_mapping
WHERE agency_code = 'TEST'
GROUP BY
        /* repeat the non-aggregating columns here (without any column aliases) */
    agency_code
  , departure_date
  , booking_class_rcd
  , origin_rcd
  , destination_rcd
ORDER BY
    departure_date DESC
```

*A non-aggregating column is any column not using an aggregate function such as sum() min() max() count() etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Adding all the aggregate and non-aggregrating fields in group by, i got the solution.

```
   Select departure_date,agency_code, origin_rcd +'-'+destination_rcd as Sector,booking_class_rcd,  count(departure_date) AS NoOfPax, SUM(fare_amount) as TotalFare, SUM(commission_amount) as TotalCommission
    from passenger_segment_mapping
  WHERE agency_code='TEST'
  Group BY departure_date, agency_code, origin_rcd, passenger_check_in_status_rcd, destination_rcd,booking_class_rcd, fare_amount, commission_amount
  ORDER BY departure_date asc
```

Comment: don't include the aggregating columns `fare_amount, commission_amount`